# Multiply TranslateAnimation in AnimationSet dont work

Tags: android, animation, multiplication

I want my ImageView to first go from the center of the screen and outside the screen on the left side, then I want it to move from outside the screen on the right side and into center of the screen.

But it's only going from the right side of the screen into center, then pauses and then goes to the left side on the screen. It does that No matter how I do. Here's the code:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth(); 

    final AnimationSet anmSet;

    anmSet = new AnimationSet(hasFocus);
    imgCenter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgCenter);
    btnGoLeft = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnGoLeft);
    imgCenter.setImageDrawable(list.get(0).getImage());
    TranslateAnimation moveBack = new TranslateAnimation(0,-500, 0, 0);
    moveBack.setDuration(500);
    moveBack.setStartOffset(200);
    anmSet.addAnimation(moveBack);

    TranslateAnimation moveLeft = new TranslateAnimation(width,width/2-imgCenter.getWidth()/2-60, 0, 0); 
    moveLeft.setDuration(500);
    moveLeft.setStartOffset(2000);
    anmSet.addAnimation(moveLeft);

    btnGoLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgCenter.startAnimation(anmSet);
        }
    });  
}
```